# Using out keyword in iterator is violation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I'm creating a mesh with vertices and triangles. I would like to assign the value of triangles in my MonoBehavior through `out` keyword:

```
public IEnumerable grabTriangle(int xSize, int zSize, out int[] triangles)
{
    triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];
    int vert = 0;
    int tris = 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
        {
            triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
            triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xSize+1;
            triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
            triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
            triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xSize + 1;
            triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xSize + 2;

            vert++;
            tris += 6;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.01f);
        }

        vert++;
    }
}
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

> Iterators can not have out parameters.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Move the assignment outside the method call and remove the `out` keyword

Comment: what is the point of `yield return new WaitForSeconds(.01f);` ?

Comment: @GuruStron It just yields periodically for the sake of animating

Comment: @Igor i need the enumerable to be able to animate the view :(

Comment: `triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];` ← that is the assignment, move that to outside this method call. Then remove the `out` keyword from the `int[] triangles` method parameter. So your method signature becomes `public IEnumerable grabTriangle(int xSize, int zSize, int[] triangles)`.

Comment: @Igor I did!... How do I call IEnumerable in the Monobehavior and assign it to triangles in monobehaviour?

Comment: @user1241241 why then not just return `IEnumerable` of triangles and let the user do anything he wants with them?

Comment: @GuruStron I tried it as `foreach (var value in _params.grabTriangle(xSize, zSize))
         {
             yield return value;
         }` but how do I assign the value to the triangles?

Comment: I would recommend introducing `struct Triangle`  and return instances of it. It would make much cleaner API.

Comment: Could you please share an example? :)

Comment: `var triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6]; foreach (var value in _params.grabTriangle(xSize, zSize, triangles)) { yield return value; }`

Comment: @Igor that works! if you could please post it as an answer, I will accept :)